# Can not delete folders on SAMBA mount point as root. Error: Directory not empty

Tags: samba, cifs

I have a remote SAMBA folder mounted as:

```
# /etc/fstab

//remote/backup /backup cifs iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp 0 0
```

But I can't delete some empty folders as root:

```
root@server $> mount /backup
root@server $> cd /backup
root@server $> ls -al 2019-06-08/

total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jun 24 10:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Aug  9 05:33 ..

root@server $> rm -rf 2019-06-08

rm: cannot remove '2019-06-08': Directory not empty

root@server $> lsof +D 2019-06-08
root@server $>
```

There are any way to delete this folders?

Thanks!

Comment: Who's the owner of that directory on the file shares _server_? And what user is the local root account mapped to there?

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't know, is a Samba as Service mount point.